# Best approach to update and apply CUs for SharePoint farm . should i manually install CU or i should use windows update

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, installation, patching

I got confused on how i should update my SharePoint 2013 farm. for example now my windows update tool mentioned that i have 4 updates for SharePoint 2013 regarding December 2014 CU. now some articles says that it is better to manually install these updates while other are saying that using windows update tools is the recommended approach since it will only show the necessary updates based on my current farm settings. can anyone adivce on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my little experience with SharePoint and A lot of Discussion with MSFT folks. I come to this Point

- First, you have to make sure you need CU to Fix a problem in your Farm
- Dont apply those CU /Fixes from Windows Update.Always Turn off Automatic Update on Server
- Dowload the CU from MSFT site and apply.

You need to plan it, test it, schedule a down time. Many problems if your automatic updates enabled and you never know if a fix applied which need Config wizard to be run.

Read this Blog, will clear you alot of things: [SharePoint patching demystified](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2014/08/19/sharepoint-patching-demystified.aspx)

Comment: why i should not apply those fixes from windows update ? i know that i need o test the CU before applying them to live server. for example in my case i install the CU using windows update on dev server ,i test them to make sure everything is working well, then i install CU on staging and test them,,, after that i apply them to live. for example on December CU they mentioned  there is a security fix when opening a document and other improvements so i need to get these updates,,

Comment: Again i know that i need to test them before applying them to live server. but the question is why i should not use windows update to install CU? currently i set the windows update not to install any updates unless i mentioned. so windows update will not install any update automatically , it only checks if there are any updates and notify me if i want to install them or not... can you adivce

Comment: their is no hard n fast rule, But if you read the artical which i mentioned...you will understand about the CU & uber package. Also One more thing MSFT making many changes with CU releases. You can do it via windows Update but One thing I noticed Windows Update having only current fix while if you directly apply CU then those include the OLD fix as well.

Comment: so now if i want to make sure my SharePoint is update to date ,, what i should do exactly ? from the link you specified the Windows update only include Public updates , while uber package include everything i need,, is this correct ? second question in my case if want to get all the latest packagies (uber updates) what i should install ?

Comment: seems that after august 2014 CU , there is not any uber packages any more ... so how i can make sure that i got all these updates ,, should i manually install august, September, October, November + December CUs ?please advice on this ? i know that i need to test, and this what i am planning to do . i need to get all the latest updates test them inside the Dev environemnt, then if they work well i will update the live server...

Comment: that's not true, December CU is Server(Uber) Package. http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2014/12/09/december-2014-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-has-been-released.aspx

Comment: this can not be more confusing ,,,, so now December CU is Uber again !!!. but i still need to install it manually is this correct ? and it will not be fully applied using windows update ? can you adivce ,, and thanks very much for the great help...

Comment: Yes you need to apply manually, Once you done you farm will full patched. AFIK windows update will not fully patched it.

Comment: ok but since i have already run windows update and install the related PU for December 2014 on my DEv machine,, so does it cause any problem if i manually install the CU manully? will it override the windows updates december 2014 PU ?

Comment: I am not sure because i never been in this sitution....we disable windows update....I think it will over write or skipp the portion which already applied.

Comment: ok i will try this since i am working on the Dev server.... so the update which i were installing using windows updates only cover security fixes and major problems, is this correct ? while CU which i will install manully contains more updates,, so the possibility of breaking exsisting functionalities will be more? so i need to test this heavily before applying the changies on production server ?

Comment: as this is dev farm so less risk, but i am +ve that nothing will break, rather CU if any hotfix already applied then skip that one and move next

Comment: no i mean that i have never manually installed any CU before,,, so there are many updates & fixes which have not been applied inside my farm,, as i only have been applying the PU not the full CU. so the rick is coming from the CU fixes that have not been applied ...

Comment: for December CU , Be aware that all Updates for SharePoint 2013 require SharePoint Server 2013 SP1 OR March 2013 PU for SharePoint 2013 to be installed first.

Comment: yes i already have SP2013 SP1 installed ... is this ok ?